# Remove old DC as Nameserver from DNS

Tags: dns

I want to remove an old server from all Forward and Reverse DNS Lookup zones where he is a nameserver.
Is there a simple way to do this via powershell?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

```
$myDNSServer = "servername@domain.de"
$DNSZones = Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service PrimaryDC)
foreach($aZone in $DNSZones)
{
    Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $aZone.ZoneName -RRType Ns -RecordData $myDNSServer -ComputerName $PDCE -Force
}
```

This script will remove all the records you searched for from the ServerResourceRecords.